# Current State of Mouse using IronPython and .Net

Tags: c#, python, .net, python-2.7, ironpython

I am running Python inside Grasshopper which is a plug-in for Rhino3d. I can easily get the mouse position, but fail to just check whether a mouse button is currently pressed. How exactly the piece of software in which this script is running is organized is unknown, but I cannot setup any handlers using Python.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) for VK_LBUTTON or VK_RBUTTON. Or use [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) depending on your requirements. Be sure to read the documentation in the GetAsyncKeyState link regarding mouse buttons. Here's the signature for it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode);
```

Comment: "This example requires that the MouseDown, MouseMove, and MouseUp events are connected to the event handlers defined in the example." I can't do this...